# Logout functionality in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to provide in my app the logout functionality, I would like to know if this way is a good approach to continue.Classes involved are described below:

the first one is the AuthViewCoordinator, which class redirects to the user to auth screens

```js
protocol AuthViewCoordinatorDelegate: class {
    func authCompleted(coordinator: AuthViewCoordinator)
}

class AuthViewCoordinator: Coordinator {

    weak var fromViewController: UIViewController?
    weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    weak var delegate: AuthViewCoordinatorDelegate?

    init(fromViewController: UIViewController, delegate: AuthViewCoordinatorDelegate) {
        self.fromViewController = fromViewController
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func start() {
        let authViewController = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AuthViewController") as! AuthViewController
        authViewController.coordinator = self
        let navigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: authViewController)
        navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        fromViewController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

    func userDidSelectLogin() {
        let loginViewController = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        loginViewController.viewModel.coordinator = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func userDidSelectSignUp() {
        let signupViewController = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
        signupViewController.viewModel.coordinator = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signupViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func userDidLogin() {
        navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.delegate?.authCompleted(coordinator: self)
    }

    func userDidSignUp() {
        navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.delegate?.authCompleted(coordinator: self)
    }

}
```

And the 2nd one is an external class called SessionController. In this class I'm trying to call AuthViewCoordinator().start() inside the function logout immediately after the tokens have been removed to show again the auth screen to the user, but the output is

> Use of unresolved identifier 'AuthViewCoordinator'

```js
public class SessionController{

    public enum SessionState {
        case anonymous
        case authenticated
        case notAuthenticated
    }

    let service: Service
    let sessionProvider: SessionProvider

    convenience public init() {
        self.init(service: Service.instance, sessionProvider: SessionProvider.instance)
    }

    init(service: Service, sessionProvider: SessionProvider) {
        self.service = service
        self.sessionProvider = sessionProvider
    }

    public func getMe(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()){
        service.execute(resource: Login.getMe()) { (result) in
            if let error = result.error {
                completion(error)
            } else if let session = result.value {
                print("\n session \(session)\n")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    public func logout() {
        self.sessionProvider.removeUserToken()
        self.sessionProvider.removeInstanceToken()
        self.sessionProvider.removeAnonymousToken()
        AuthViewController().start()
    }

    public func state() -> SessionState {
        if let _ = sessionProvider.getUserToken() {
            print("###### authenticated #########")
            return .authenticated
        } else if let _ = sessionProvider.getAnonymousToken() {
            print("###### anonymous #########")
            return .anonymous
        } else {
            print("###### notAuthenticated #########")
            return .notAuthenticated
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean `AuthViewCoordinator().start()` instead of `AuthViewController().start()`?

Comment: thanks seto, you are right, I've just edited the question with the correct class

Comment: what about the code inside `logout()` function?